# How to Sum array value by key for chart?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, sum

Sorry, I see multiple similar solutions but i'm unable to implement them in my situations. I tried isset to check if value exist before sum but its giving me true value and not able to add its actual value. with bellow code it's repeating the same value as long as for loop running and giving me wrong sum value. Please correct me.

I want to add array value to single array by matching key..

I have this array...

```
Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Customer] => Array
            (
                [created_by] => 3
                [amount] => 475
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Customer] => Array
            (
                [created_by] => 5
                [amount] => 199
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Customer] => Array
            (
                [created_by] => 1
                [amount] => 199
                [refund_amount] => 200
                [upgrade_amount] => 199
            )

    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [Customer] => Array
            (
                [created_by] => 1
                [amount] => 199
            )

    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [Customer] => Array
            (
                [created_by] => 4
                [upgrade_amount] => 199
            )

    )
```

)
I'm looking for result like this.....

```
Array(
[3] => Array
    (
        [sale] => 475
        [refund] => 0
        [upgrade] => 0
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [sale] => 199
        [refund] => 0
        [upgrade] => 0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [sale] => 398
        [refund] => 200
        [upgrade] => 199
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [sale] => 0
        [refund] => 0
        [upgrade] => 199
    )
```

)

I'm using this code to get my result....

```
   foreach($records as $y_key => $y_value){
            //print_r($y_value);
            if(!isset($top_performer[$y_value['Customer']['created_by']])){
                $top_performer[$y_value['Customer']['created_by']]['sale'] = 0;
                $top_performer[$y_value['Customer']['created_by']]['refund'] = 0;
                $top_performer[$y_value['Customer']['created_by']]['upgrade'] = 0;
            }
             $top_performer[$y_value['Customer']['created_by']]['sale']+= $y_value['Customer']['amount'];
             $top_performer[$y_value['Customer']['created_by']]['refund']+= $y_value['Customer']['refund_amount'];
             $top_performer[$y_value['Customer']['created_by']]['upgrade']+=$y_value['Customer']['upgrade_amount'];

        }
```

Comment: What's your current output ?

Comment: I don't get your question because your code does exactly what you need : [http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9e7f683636fcd417059e066326509addad77dc73](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9e7f683636fcd417059e066326509addad77dc73), may be it's the notices ?

Comment: Its giving me correct value at this poing but when uploading this code to the live server where n number are array its adding the last value untill foreach end their job.

Comment: Thanks @Jimbot & Sagar, I had some bug in my code, I have figured that out..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is looking good, you only need to check if array element exists

```
   foreach($records as $y_key => $y_value){
            if(!isset($top_performer[$y_value['Customer']['created_by']])){
                $top_performer[$y_value['Customer']['created_by']]['sale'] = 0;
                $top_performer[$y_value['Customer']['created_by']]['refund'] = 0;
                $top_performer[$y_value['Customer']['created_by']]['upgrade'] = 0;
            }
             $top_performer[$y_value['Customer']['created_by']]['sale'] += isset($y_value['Customer']['amount']) ? $y_value['Customer']['amount'] : 0;
             $top_performer[$y_value['Customer']['created_by']]['refund'] += isset($y_value['Customer']['refund_amount']) ? $y_value['Customer']['refund_amount'] : 0;
             $top_performer[$y_value['Customer']['created_by']]['upgrade'] += isset($y_value['Customer']['upgrade_amount']) ? $y_value['Customer']['upgrade_amount'] : 0;
    }
```

Comment: With PHP7, can abbreviate `isset($y_value['Customer']['amount']) ? $y_value['Customer']['amount'] : 0` to `$y_value['Customer']['amount']??0`

Comment: Thanks @ivan Bolnikh for help. I was already tried this solutions but I was still getting wrong result on live server. After getting the same answer I had tried I realize that there my be other problem and I check my code again. I found that my main array has duplicate data that's why I was getting wrong result. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry @Nigel Ren, I'm still using older PHP 5.6 :)